# a page in a page without iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am trying to find a way how to put a page in another page without iframe and inculde the header and footer.I have try iframe but i didn't like it.This is what the layout would look like, 
i made a page call help.php in this file i include the follow code below

```
<?php include("connection.php"); include("header.php"); ?>
  <div class="container">
( i want to put this url here support.sitename.com )
</div>
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
```

it should be like this sitename.com/help.php
i have another page support.sitename.com ( this one is using a help desk software call HESK

i am trying to add support.sitename.com into sitename.com/help.php but i don't want to use iframe  how can i do this

Comment: Take a look at AJAX - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  Demo: http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-ajax-tabs.html

Comment: Ajax is not always recommanded if the page you want to integrate is not on the same domain. You can try by retreiving the HTML code of the page you want to include with echo file_gets_contents('http://support.sitename.com'), or with CURL wich is made to get distant pages, but this will include all the page code including html and head... http://nc.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php

Comment: Ah, I hadn't though of the fact that it's not on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php include("connection.php"); include("header.php"); ?>
  <div class="container">
<?php 
$html =  file_get_contents("http://support.sitename.com"); 
$html = preg_replace('%href="/(.*?)"%si', 'href="http://support.sitename.com/$1"', $html);
echo $html;
?>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I just your code but when i click a link inside the page it  open a new page to my homepage

Comment: it's because the links are relative and not absolute, use a regex to change the links (http://compugoddess.com/relative-vs-absolute-links/)

Comment: sorry i am new to this don't get mad do you mean something like this `<?php echo file_get_contents("http://support.sitename.com/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/"; ?>`